# How to count non-self citations of articles?

Tags: citations, google-scholar, tools

In Google Scholar, I can view the number of citations of each article, but this includes self-citations. Is there a way to view the number of non-self citations?

In [this tweet from 2019](https://twitter.com/dsquintana/status/1114980650816294918), the author suggests a way to calculate this number for a specific article. But is there a way to do this automatically for all my articles?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55202/should-self-citations-be-excluded-when-calculating-the-h-index

Comment: On why you might not want to do this: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/what-is-a-fair-metric-for-assessing-the-citation-impact-of-journals-across-disci https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41740/h-index-any-quantitative-or-other-measures-on-how-well-h-index-actually-measu

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist The promotion committee in my university asks me to report the citation counts of my articles, both with and without self-citations. This is not the only measure by which they decide on promotion - it is just one of many tools. In any case, I have to report this number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scopus tool ("h-graph") allows one to turn self-citations on or off for a given scholar if you have access (my institution provides access to the full tool after linking them with Elsevier).

https://www.scopus.com/freelookup/form/author.uri

Note that the total citation count will differ from Google Scholar, even if the profiles are aligned as to which publications count.

Comment: Great tool! But I do not see there a way to count the non-self-citations of individual papers.

Comment: I don't know. For an individual paper, maybe you can count manually.