# What are A and A* conference ranks?

Tags: conference, terminology, ranking

Following [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/93026/what-are-some-metrics-to-rank-conferences) question, what does A and A* mean for conference rank? Is there a site where can I get information for conference rank?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In computer science, the most important ranking is the one maintained by CORE, the Computing Research and Education Association of Australasia. It uses ranks such as A* (=exceptional), A (=excellent), B (=good to very good), and C (=sound and satisfactory).

They make the criteria for the different ranks explicit in a formal [ranking description document](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnx3d3djb3JlZWR1fGd4OjJjNjkxOWE1NWQ4ZGY5MjU).

Also, they have an [online database](http://www.core.edu.au/conference-portal) with their rankings.

Comment: Thanks @lighthouse keeper, Is there also an online database for journals (Q1 etc.)?

Comment: @Avi At least for my subfield of CS, there's no universally accepted ranking of journals. The closest thing would be rankings based on H-index and/or Impact Factor, listed on sites such as Scimago.